# Google Spreadsheet script to choose a column based on two values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Dear Wonderful Scripters,

Apologies for not knowing all the lingo, I'm a novice at best but I've hit the wall. I am trying to hide/show columns based on two values in different cells.

I have a sheet named "Start" which has a value that changes (Year) in O2. This corresponds to a column on a sheet named "Subjects" (see pic). Subjects has a list of subjects and columns labelled "Prep, Year 1-2, Year 3-4 and Year 5-6". I would like to script a solution that checks the value on Start and then reads the column on Subjects for 1s and 0s and shows/hides columns on another sheet named "Reports".

For example, if O2 on Start says Year 1-2, then the script looks at Subjects (D1) and then shows or hides (1 or 0) columns on Reports that correspond with those subjects (eg Preps on have IPDIP so if the value is Year 1-2, then the column on Reports will be hidden. There is more than one column on Reports that will be hidden or shown.

I'm currently using this script:

```
function ShowHideSubjects() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reports");

  sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns())

  var condition = sheet.getRange("Subjects!C2").getValue();
    if (condition = 1) {
    sheet.showColumns(10,1)
    }
  var condition = sheet.getRange("Subjects!C2").getValue();
    if (condition = 0) {
    sheet.hideColumns(10,1)
  }
}
```

Here's some pics to explain.

[Value on Start][1]

[Subjects Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDBb.png)

[Columns on Reports sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQGNy.png)

Your help would be greatly appreciated. This Google Spreadsheet currently saves our school $1000s a year and it would be awesome to get this sorted out.

Peace and thanks,

Wayne

Comment: condition = 1  is an assignment not a comparison.  Take it a little further and see if you can figure  it out on your own.

Comment: Yep, got that far :) Removed the "" and it seems to work :) I still don't understand how I get it to check the start sheet AND the Subjects sheet. At the moment, the script only checks the cells in Subjects. If I continue this way, I will need to make four different copies of the same sheet.

Answer (score 1):

## The Column Chooser

#### Here's the code

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('ShowHideSubjects','ShowHideSubjects')
    .addToUi();
}

function ShowHideSubjects() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
  var subjectsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Subjects')
  var startSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start');
  var startSubjectsRange = startSheet.getRange('O2');
  
  var reportsSheetDataRange = reportsSheet.getDataRange();
  var reportsSheetDataArray = reportsSheetDataRange.getValues();
  var reportsSheetDataRangeLastRow = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastRow();
  var reportsSheetDataRangeLastColumn = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn();
  for(var i = 0;i < reportsSheetDataRangeLastRow;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0;j < reportsSheetDataRangeLastColumn;j ++)
    {
      if(reportsSheetDataArray[i][j] == 'IPDIP')
      {
        var ipdipRow = i + 1;
        var ipdipCol = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  var reportsNumColumns = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - ipdipCol + 1
  //check that its the right reports range
  //reportsSheet.setActiveSelection(reportsSheet.getRange(ipdipRow, ipdipCol, 1 , reportsNumColumns));
  var reportsHeaderRange = reportsSheet.getRange(ipdipRow, ipdipCol, 1 , reportsNumColumns);
 
  var subjectsSheetDataRange = subjectsSheet.getDataRange();
  var subjectsSheetDataArray = subjectsSheetDataRange.getValues();
  var subjectsSheetDataRangeLastRow = subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow();
  var subjectsSheetDataRangeLastColumn = subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn();
  for(var i = 0;i < subjectsSheetDataRangeLastRow;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0;j < subjectsSheetDataRangeLastColumn;j ++)
    {
      if(subjectsSheetDataArray[i][j] == 'Subjects')
      {
        var subjectsRow = i + 1;
        var subjectsCol = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  //check that its the right subjects range
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow() - subjectsRow + 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1));
  var subjectsShowHideHeaderRange = subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol, 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1);
  var subjectsShowHideHeaderArray = subjectsShowHideHeaderRange.getValues();
  var subjectsShowHideRange = subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow() - subjectsRow + 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1);
  //checked subjectsShowHideRange
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsShowHideRange);
  var w = subjectsShowHideHeaderRange.getWidth();
  var startString = startSubjectsRange.getValue();
  for(var i = 0;i < w;i++)
  {
    if(subjectsShowHideHeaderArray[0][i] == startString)
    {
      var subjectsShowHideColumn = subjectsCol + i;
      break;
    }
  }
  //checked the subjectsShowHideColumn
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( startSubjectsRange.getValue() + ' is column ' + subjectsShowHideColumn + ' on the subjects page. And subjects is on column ' + subjectsCol + '.');
  //Checked the subjectsShowHideRange
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsShowHideRange);
  var subjectsShowHideArray = subjectsShowHideRange.getValues();
  var subjectsShowHideRangeHeight = subjectsShowHideRange.getHeight();
  //for(var i = 0;i < subjectsShowHideRangeHeight;i++)
  for(var i = subjectsShowHideRangeHeight -1;i >= 0;i--)
  {
    var subject = subjectsShowHideArray[i][0];
    var show = subjectsShowHideArray[i][subjectsShowHideColumn-subjectsCol];
    var showhidecolsS=reportsColumnHeaderMatch(ipdipRow,ipdipCol,reportsNumColumns,subject);
    if(showhidecolsS)
    {
      var showhidecolsA=showhidecolsS.split(',');
      if(showhidecolsA)
      {
        for(var j = 0; j < showhidecolsA.length; j++)
        {
          columnsShowHide(showhidecolsA[j],show);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function columnsShowHide(column, show)
{
  var column = (typeof(column) !== 'undefined')? column: 0; 
  var show = (typeof(show) !== 'undefined')? show: 1;
  if(column == 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Error: The column parameter passed to columnsShowHide is undefined.');
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    switch(show)
    {
      case 1:
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').showColumns(column); 
        //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange(1,column,10,1).setBackground('yellow');
        break;
      case 0:
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').hideColumns(column);
        //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange(1,column,10,1).setBackground('white');
        break;
      default:
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Show parameter is out of range not 0 or 1 in function columnsShowHide');
    } 
  }
}

function reportsColumnHeaderMatch(row, col, numcolumns, subject)
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports');
  var rng = sht.getRange(row, col, 1, numcolumns);
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  var result = '';
  var firsttime = true;
  
  for(var i = 0;i < numcolumns;i++)
  {
    //var s = rngA[0][i].toString();
    var s = rngA[0][i];
    var re = new RegExp('^' + subject);
    if(s.match(re))
    {
      if(!firsttime)result += ',';
      result += col + i;
      firsttime = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
  // Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
    var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
    var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 250;
    var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
    var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
       .createHtmlOutput(html)
       .setWidth(width)
       .setHeight(height);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```

#### Slight Problem

I have a working version but I ran into a problem. I'm using a regular expression RegExp('^' + subject).  What this allows me to do is to build the regular expression on the fly.  When the subject is IPDIP the regular expression ^IPDIP matches all of the characters of the IPDIP column header and since the second row of Year 1-2 is 0 then column IPDIP is turned off but then the next subject is IPD and the regular expression ^IPD also matches IPDIP and the third row of Year 1-2 now turns off IPDIP which is probably a problem. I was planning on using this  technique to match the rest of the columns because the subjects are only the first three letters of the rest of the column headers and that would be a great way to catch them.  So I guess the question is do you want IPDIP on or off in for the Year 1-2 reports.

Are all of the Reports column header names six characters or greater?  I could take advantage of that because IPDIP is only 5 characters.  So I could apply my regular expression only to headers that are 6 characters or greater.  But I need your input on that because I'm guessing that the actual Reports sheet is probably a little wider than the one I see.

I guess another solution could be to work my way up through from the bottom of the subjects column to the top then IPDIP would always be the 5 character match.

I just noticed that we have the same problem with ICT and ICTICT.

For now I decided to just reverse the order of going through the subjects column from bottom to top.  As long as you always put the longest strings that have overlapping matches on the top you should be okay.

#### Just so that you know

One of things I did with this code is to make the origin of the tables be the location of the Subjects Header on the subjects page and the IPDIP header on the Reports pages.  So this makes possible for you to move the tables (i.e. add columns to the left and above the current data).  The program figures out where the data is based up these two key locations and readjusts itself automatically.  Another way of saying that is to say that it doesn't assume that the first row/column in your table is row/column 1/A

Comment: Awesome, that's almost right. The columns in the Reports are the first three letters of the subject. For example, PLE (B5 on Subjects) corresponds to columns in Reports that sEVtart with that code. You can see in the example IPD relates to IPDSOC_PRE (column K) through to IPDTEA (column N). It varies between one column and six columns. I was planning on doing this by using something like:  

    var condition = sheet.getRange("Subjects!C2").getValue();
    if (condition = 1) {
    sheet.showColumns(10,1)
    sheet.showColumns(11,1)
    sheet.showColumns(12,1) etc.
    }

Comment: Okay, let me think about that some more then I'll come back with a summary what I think you want and you can adjust from there.  ... We could use a regular expression to match the 3 letter prefixes  with something like /^PLE/ case sensitive and that will match the prefix. Using /^IPDIP/ will match IPDIP so that should work okay.  It's starting to make sense.  I've got several things to do today but I'll be back as soon as I can.

Comment: Mate, any help is most appreciated. :)

Comment: Hello Wayne, I have a working version but I ran into a little problem perhaps you can help me with.  It's explain in the section above entitled "Slight Problem".  I'm sure it's solvable but I would be nice if you could take a look at it for me.  I need to test the code some more and then I'll post it and we can both see it.

Comment: I've created a test sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BMOdcZUPWQZbVfcOUGiyANFGd-kdEYAr0DH2himlwvk

I get a number of "Show parameter is out of range not 0 or 1 in function columnsShowHide" errors when I run the script. It otherwise works well. 

The codes are not set in stone, so if we need to change the name of IPDIP and ICTICT, we can.

Comment: OK, got it to work by deleting the empty rows on the Subjects sheet. Works perfectly! I changed some of the names of the subjects (IPDIP is now DIPIP and ICTICT is now 12ICT) and every year level works well. 

This is awesome! I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: Cool I'm glad it works.  I can go back into the code and rearrange the loop on the subjectsShowHideRange which is the last loop so that it iterates from from top to bottom.  It doesn't make that much difference to me but it might make more sense to someone who has to maintain it.  The old for loop statement is still in there commented out.  I used big variable names so that it would make more sense to people reading the code who know how the program works.  I asked for edit access but since you got it work then maybe I don't need it.  Come on back if you need any more help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Works exactly as requested, first try :-) Thanks to Cooper for the hard work.

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('ShowHideSubjects','ShowHideSubjects')
    .addToUi();
}

function ShowHideSubjects() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
  var subjectsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Subjects')
  var startSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start');
  var startSubjectsRange = startSheet.getRange('O2');

  var reportsSheetDataRange = reportsSheet.getDataRange();
  var reportsSheetDataArray = reportsSheetDataRange.getValues();
  var reportsSheetDataRangeLastRow = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastRow();
  var reportsSheetDataRangeLastColumn = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn();
  for(var i = 0;i < reportsSheetDataRangeLastRow;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0;j < reportsSheetDataRangeLastColumn;j ++)
    {
      if(reportsSheetDataArray[i][j] == 'IPDIP')
      {
        var ipdipRow = i + 1;
        var ipdipCol = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  var reportsNumColumns = reportsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - ipdipCol + 1
  //check that its the right reports range
  //reportsSheet.setActiveSelection(reportsSheet.getRange(ipdipRow, ipdipCol, 1 , reportsNumColumns));
  var reportsHeaderRange = reportsSheet.getRange(ipdipRow, ipdipCol, 1 , reportsNumColumns);

  var subjectsSheetDataRange = subjectsSheet.getDataRange();
  var subjectsSheetDataArray = subjectsSheetDataRange.getValues();
  var subjectsSheetDataRangeLastRow = subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow();
  var subjectsSheetDataRangeLastColumn = subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn();
  for(var i = 0;i < subjectsSheetDataRangeLastRow;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0;j < subjectsSheetDataRangeLastColumn;j ++)
    {
      if(subjectsSheetDataArray[i][j] == 'Subjects')
      {
        var subjectsRow = i + 1;
        var subjectsCol = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  //check that its the right subjects range
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow() - subjectsRow + 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1));
  var subjectsShowHideHeaderRange = subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol, 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1);
  var subjectsShowHideHeaderArray = subjectsShowHideHeaderRange.getValues();
  var subjectsShowHideRange = subjectsSheet.getRange(subjectsRow, subjectsCol,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastRow() - subjectsRow + 1 ,subjectsSheetDataRange.getLastColumn() - subjectsCol + 1);
  //checked subjectsShowHideRange
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsShowHideRange);
  var w = subjectsShowHideHeaderRange.getWidth();
  var startString = startSubjectsRange.getValue();
  for(var i = 0;i < w;i++)
  {
    if(subjectsShowHideHeaderArray[0][i] == startString)
    {
      var subjectsShowHideColumn = subjectsCol + i;
      break;
    }
  }
  //checked the subjectsShowHideColumn
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( startSubjectsRange.getValue() + ' is column ' + subjectsShowHideColumn + ' on the subjects page. And subjects is on column ' + subjectsCol + '.');
  //Checked the subjectsShowHideRange
  //subjectsSheet.setActiveSelection(subjectsShowHideRange);
  var subjectsShowHideArray = subjectsShowHideRange.getValues();
  var subjectsShowHideRangeHeight = subjectsShowHideRange.getHeight();
  //for(var i = 0;i < subjectsShowHideRangeHeight;i++)
  for(var i = subjectsShowHideRangeHeight -1;i >= 0;i--)
  {
    var subject = subjectsShowHideArray[i][0];
    var show = subjectsShowHideArray[i][subjectsShowHideColumn-subjectsCol];
    var showhidecolsS=reportsColumnHeaderMatch(ipdipRow,ipdipCol,reportsNumColumns,subject);
    if(showhidecolsS)
    {
      var showhidecolsA=showhidecolsS.split(',');
      if(showhidecolsA)
      {
        for(var j = 0; j < showhidecolsA.length; j++)
        {
          columnsShowHide(showhidecolsA[j],show);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function columnsShowHide(column, show)
{
  var column = (typeof(column) !== 'undefined')? column: 0; 
  var show = (typeof(show) !== 'undefined')? show: 1;
  if(column == 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Error: The column parameter passed to columnsShowHide is undefined.');
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    switch(show)
    {
      case 1:
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').showColumns(column); 
        //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange(1,column,10,1).setBackground('yellow');
        break;
      case 0:
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').hideColumns(column);
        //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange(1,column,10,1).setBackground('white');
        break;
      default:
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Show parameter is out of range not 0 or 1 in function columnsShowHide');
    } 
  }
}

function reportsColumnHeaderMatch(row, col, numcolumns, subject)
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reports');
  var rng = sht.getRange(row, col, 1, numcolumns);
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  var result = '';
  var firsttime = true;

  for(var i = 0;i < numcolumns;i++)
  {
    //var s = rngA[0][i].toString();
    var s = rngA[0][i];
    var re = new RegExp('^' + subject);
    if(s.match(re))
    {
      if(!firsttime)result += ',';
      result += col + i;
      firsttime = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
  // Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
    var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
    var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 250;
    var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
    var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
       .createHtmlOutput(html)
       .setWidth(width)
       .setHeight(height);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```